# If you have half of a Canadian $20 bill, is it worth $10?

Tags: law, canada

I recently saw this tweet by What The F*** Facts:
[image]

> In Canada, if you have half of a $20 bill, it is worth $10.

Is there any truth to this claim?

Comment: This is surprisingly hard to answer.  The Bank of Canada site says they'll reimburse you for mutilated currency, but it says jack-all about how *much* of the bill you need to get your money.  In contrast, the US has a clear policy of "51% = full value, anything less = nothing".

Comment: FWIW: In Australia, the [Reserve Bank will pay out](http://banknotes.rba.gov.au/damaged-banknotes/damaged-banknotes-policy/) the percentage undamaged, if it is 20-80% undamaged, or the full amount if it is more intact.

Comment: Backing up Mark's comment: [Here is the process](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/contaminated-and-mutilated-bank-notes/) and [here is the vague reimbursement policy](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Policy_Reimbursement_contaminated_Mutilated_Notes.pdf).

Comment: The picture is wrong though: that's a picture of an American banknote, not a Canadian.

Comment: I'm vaguely recalling the US Federal Reserve System changed the rules on reimbursing for damaged currency several times during the latter half of the 20th century.  At one time there were several different, er, "cutoff points", for partial reimbursement.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe they meant Quebec? According to a [CBC](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/montreal/demi-canadian-bill-becoming-local-currency-in-quebec-s-gasp%C3%A9-region-1.3207027) article published in 2015:

> Residents in Quebec's Gaspé region are cutting Canadian bills in half
> to create a new local currency they call the "demi."
>
> No one really knows who started the practice, but $5, $10 and $20
> bills, sliced down the middle, have been showing up since the spring.
>
> Residents and some local merchants have been using them, accepting
> their value as half of the original bill.
>
> "It's money that can only be circulated among these local users,"
> said Patrick DuBois, a demi user from Carleton-sur-Mer, Que.
>
> "No one else will accept it anywhere right now."
>
> [...]
>
> The Bank of Canada says the practice isn't illegal, but also isn't
> advisable.
>
> "The Bank of Canada feels that writing and markings on bank notes or
> mutilating them [is] inappropriate as they are a symbol of our country
> and a source of national pride," Bank of Canada spokeswoman Josianne
> Ménard said in a written statement.
>
> "Canadians can help keep their bank notes in good condition so they
> circulate longer."
>
> Martin Zibeau, a demi user from Saint-Siméon, said it's impossible to
> know how many people are using the quirky local currency, but he
> personally knows of more than a dozen.
>
> "It's something that's still developing. It's funny --- there are a
> lot of tourists who have seen it and spread the word across Quebec."
>
> Zibeau says he doesn't see anything wrong with the demi because the
> bills are still being used as currency.
>
> "In the worst case, if we find ourselves in trouble, we just need to
> make a call out to collect all the bills with the same serial number
> to restore the value. We can always put them back together."
>
> Bank of Canada policy says [it can refuse to reimburse anyone who
> wants a replacement
> bill](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Policy_Reimbursement_contaminated_Mutilated_Notes.pdf) if "the
> notes have otherwise been altered or damaged deliberately or in a
> systematic fashion."

Comment: Considering that 2015 article mentions that it started in the spring, and the tweet in question is from 2014, it seems like they probably aren't directly related.  Another answer also points to a 2009 source (of questionable quality) that says the same thing.  This is interesting; but if anything this is more likely an effect of that rule, than the cause of the Tweet.

Answer (score 5):

The [Bank of Canada Contaminated and Mutilated Bank Notes webpage](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/contaminated-and-mutilated-bank-notes/) makes no specific mention of valuation based on degree of mutilation.

Furthermore, there is a document titled [Policy on the Reimbursement of Contaminated or Mutilated Canadian Bank Notes](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Policy_Reimbursement_contaminated_Mutilated_Notes.pdf) which also does not provide any breakdown of how it judges mutilation or value of mutilated bank notes. It does provide this non-specific advice:

> In exercising its discretion to reimburse contaminated 
>   or mutilated notes, the Bank has an obligation to 
>   exercise due diligence in the evaluation of all claims. 
>   The Bank seeks to determine the legitimacy of all 
>   aspects of a claim, including the identity of the 
>   claimant, value of the notes submitted, source of the 
>   notes and nature of the damage.
>
> Bank staff will, subject to any health and safety 
>   issues noted below, carefully examine notes 
>   submitted for reimbursement and assess the value of 
>   the claim.
>
> As guidance to claimants, the Bank will not 
>   reimburse a claim for mutilated notes where in the
>   Bank’s opinion there is a reasonable doubt, based 
>   on research, evidence or common sense, that all or a 
>   part of the claim is legitimate. For example, the Bank 
>   will not reimburse a claim where in its opinion:
>
> - the identity of the claimant cannot be 
>     substantiated;
> - the notes are counterfeit or there are reasons 
>     to believe that the notes were acquired or are 
>     connected to money laundering or other criminal 
>     acts;
> - there has been an attempt to defraud the Bank 
>     or there exists contradictory or improbable 
>     explanations about significant aspects of the 
>     claim, such as how the notes were damaged or 
>     how they came into possession of the claimant;
> - any of the security features of the notes have 
>     been removed or altered or where the notes have 
>     otherwise been altered or damaged deliberately 
>     or in a systematic fashion, including dyed or 
>     chemically washed or treated, by a process that 
>     could be reasonably expected to have the effect 
>     of altering them.

In the absence of any official public policy I would argue that other answers may be speculative in nature.

Answer (score 2):

The only source on the web that I've found which says so is https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090418160700AA5Zhfb from 2009 which says,

> A genuine note that has become worn or sustained minor damage in circulation can be exchanged for full face value. These notes are classified as unfit notes and may have small pieces missing or small holes (less than 20 per cent of the note missing in both cases), have been torn, have heat damage affecting less than 20 per cent of the note, have adhesive tape on them or have been stapled or defaced. These notes can continue to be offered and accepted in transactions because they are worth full face value. The BOC asks banks, other authorised deposit-taking institutions and cash centre operators, to remove unfit notes from circulation when they are returned to them by their customers.
>
> The BOC adopts the following policy: 
>   For determining the value of damaged notes where pieces are missing:
>
> - If less than 20 per cent is missing: The note is regarded as unfit and full face value is paid, even if the note is otherwise worn.
> - If between 20 per cent and 80 per cent is missing: The note is regarded as incomplete and value is paid in proportion with the percentage remaining, e.g. half face value if half the note is present, even if the note is otherwise worn. The presence or absence of specific features such as the serial number(s) or the clear window is not a factor when determining value.
> - If more than 80 per cent is missing: No value is paid.

That seems to be to be a genuine quote (e.g. IMO the factual reasoning is plausible, and so is the literary style, as is the BOC contact information including a bilingual email address at the bottom of the quote), but I haven't found (using Google) a copy of it from a more official source.

For what it's worth, https://docs.com/ZG5E contains a copy of a document which includes near-identical wording (except "RBA instead of "BOC") that purports to be from the Reserve Bank of Australia.

Comment: I am dubious about this source. It seems awfully like it was copied from Australia, and is a different approach to the BoC sources I linked to in the comments on the question.

Comment: Yes, or that Australian policy was copied from the Canadian. That one of the banks copied from the other bank both the policy and the text of the policy is not IMO implausible. The contact details like "mutilated-mutiles@bankofcanada.ca" look correct. Either someone forged the Yahoo answer, replacing "RBA" with "BOC" etc., or they copied an official Canadian document that I haven't found. The latter is more likely IMO. Does it even contradict (is it a different approach than) the "vague policy" which you referenced in a comment?

Comment: I disagree with your opinion on the probabilities, but I respect that your opinion has at least the same weight as mine. I emailed the BoC to see if they could shed light on this, and break the deadlock.

Comment: @Oddthinking http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_of_Canada says, "It is part of the "Four Nations Group" of central banks, which includes the Reserve Bank of Australia, the Bank of England, and the Bank of Mexico, that collaborate on banknote security research, testing, and development."

Comment: You know that there is no way I'm gonna accept a yahoo answers source, right?

Comment: Of note, this breakdown is distinctly different from the one in http://money.stackexchange.com/a/34019 (referencing the [Great Canadian Trivia Book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=TJM7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=bank%20of%20canada%20torn%20bill%20three%20fifths&source=bl&ots=mIuj3dzTdP&sig=wFJkfcmoing-UAQOd3RYOoyS8rg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DEa7U5v1MdCHogSdioL4BA&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=bank%20of%20canada%20torn%20bill%20three%20fifths&f=false), which itself cites a nameless "manager of operations for the Bank of Canada")

Comment: @ChrisW, you might want to check [this](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=TJM7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=In+Canada,+if+you+have+half+of+a+%2420+bill,+it+is+worth+%2410.&source=bl&ots=mIwn55CX7U&sig=n4zMz7rATpYbGYbhf1AzfAbKsBI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3V0rVaOuJdHraPHWgLgD&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=In%20Canada%2C%20if%20you%20have%20half%20of%20a%20%2420%20bill%2C%20it%20is%20worth%20%2410.&f=false) it might be helpful.

Comment: I forgot to report back: I got a return email from the Bank of Canada with links to the two documents that I already linked to above (despite me explaining I had read them) and no new information. The email was of no value at all.

Comment: This might be *right* but it's really poor evidence.

Comment: @Sklivvz I agree, that 'yahoo answers' isn't as authoritative a site as we'd like; I couldn't find other, better evidence. I think it's, at least, not worse than the evidence being question in the OP.

Comment: It needs to be *strictly* better than the claim, otherwise what's the point? :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz I think it is better. The OP presented no evidence for the claim. This presents evidence i.e. what's alleged to be a verbatim copy of an official policy. That evidence might have been falsified (Offthinking thinks it was, whereas I don't think it was), but that is 'better' than no evidence at all. Answers are supposed to present evidence for readers to weigh. You might think this evidence is light-weight, but it's more than nothing IMO.

Comment: @ChrisW: Not only Yahoo Answers isn't authoritative; it doesn't even constitute a notable claim.

Comment: @georgechalhoub Well I don't have any answer better than this for you. I think it's better than nothing, two moderators have questioned it, and 3 out of 4 voters think it's more useful than not.

Comment: @ChrisW I'm not saying it should be deleted, yeah it is better than nothing; just commenting about the source...

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that i could take 5 bills, cut 20% out of each in different sections, tape the remainders together as-needed and then tape together the cut-out pieces to form 6 'acceptable' bills? That seems like quite a loophole

Comment: @EthanTheBrave I think there's a serial number on each bill, printed in two places.

Comment: @ChrisW: Starting with five bills, one could get six 83%-complete "bills".  If, as claimed, "the presence or absence of...serial numbers is not a factor", one may be able to cut out any problematic portions of serial numbers and still have 80%-complete "bills".  At worst, one may need to use six bills to make 7, or seven to make 8.